# How to update paint shader in a custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-custom-view

I'm working in a custom view that draws a circle based on the touch position. Later I want to change the circle size and color based on the position but right now I'm worried because in the onDraw method, when I create a RadialGradient and add it to the paint.shader, Android Studio shows me a DrawAllocation warning. I want to know if there is a way to avoid this warning or if there is a better approach to achieve this, the fact is that I want to draw gradients with dynamic values, in this case, the only dynamic value I need is the center of the RadialGradient but later I will draw more circles with more gradients and I don't want to have performance issues. Hope you can help me

```kotlin
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)

    private var touch = PointF(0.0f, 0.0f)
    private val size = SIZE_DP * resources.displayMetrics.density
    private var centerX = 0f
    private var centerY = 0f

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        touch = PointF(event.x, event.y)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        centerX = w * 0.5f
        centerY = h * 0.5f
        touch = PointF(centerX, centerY)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        // Here is where the warning shows
        // I would like to have only one RadialGradient object and only change the 
        // center coordinates here something like gradient.centerX = touch.x
        paint.shader = RadialGradient(
            touch.x, touch.y, SIZE_DP * 4,
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
        canvas.drawCircle(
            touch.x, touch.y,
            size, paint
        )
        postInvalidate()
    }

    companion object {
        const val SIZE_DP = 100.0f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the gradients before, but as far as I know, when you define one (with its coordinates) you're effectively "painting" a gradient on the canvas, and when you draw a circle somewhere on that canvas, you're basically peeking through to the pre-defined gradient behind. It's not centred on the circle you're drawing.

So in that case, you *have* to create a new `RadialGradient` each time you want to draw a new circle somewhere else. The warning you're getting is basically because `onDraw` can potentially be called every frame (every 16ms or faster on some devices), and allocating stuff in there is a quick way to pile up the memory usage. But it's up to you - if you know it's only going to be called occasionally, you can just suppress the warning (put the cursor on the warning and pick one of the quick fixes)

---

One suggestion though - you're calling `postInvalidate()` (you could just use `invalidate()`) in `onDraw`, which *ensures* it will get drawn again next frame. You don't actually need to do that as far as I can tell - you only need to redraw your view when the circle changes, which is when you get another touch event, right?

So instead, you could call `invalidate()` from your `dispatchTouchEvent` method. Every time you get a new event, tell the view to update itself. You're updating the current value for `touch` in there - you could also create your `RadialGradient` in there too, and set it on `paint`. That way, your `onDraw` just needs to draw a circle using the current `paint` and `touch`. And you don't need to supress any warnings since the allocations aren't happening in there.

Since you update `touch` in `onSizeChanged` too, best put all your updates in a function, update the state in one place:

```
fun updateCirclePosition(x: Int, y: Int) {
    touch = PointF(x, y)
    paint.shader = RadialGradient(
        x, y, SIZE_DP * 4,
        Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
    )
}
```

and call that from your functions that update `touch`. That way `paint` is consistent with it. You could even get smarter with it:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    // no redrawing / reallocating unless necessary
    // you might need to check the type of event though (e.g. lifted finger)
    if (event.x != touch.x || event.y != touch.y) {
        updateCirclePosition(event.x, event.y)
        invalidate()
    }
    return true
}
```

you could even stick the `invalidate` in `updateCirclePosition` since, really, updating that position means the view contents are invalid and it needs redrawing

Comment: You are right, thanks for your advice.

Comment: @OswaldoGallo another thing you could look into is translating the canvas - basically you draw in one place, you just slide the canvas so the right point is under where you're drawing, then slide it back when you're done - a bit like a stamp: https://blog.devgenius.io/canvas-translation-and-state-management-custom-views-on-android-part-2-1428171b4eef Not really messed with that myself, but you might be able to just create one gradient in one place, always draw the circle there, and that way you don't need to create a new one in a new position. Might be worth checking out!